# How to convert a STArray to a List in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

Is there a function can do what the function `arrayToList` do:

```
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST

genArray :: ST s [Int]
genArray = do
   a <- new Array (0, 99) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
   writeArray a 0 1
   {- ... write something to the array ... -}
   return arrayToList(a)
```

If not, how to write one?

Comment: > updated  `genArray :: IO [Int]` to  `genArrat :: ST s [Int]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `IO` for this, constructing a list is a pure operation:

```
genArray :: [Int]
genArray = runST $ do
  a <- newArray (0, 99) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
  writeArray a 0 1
  {- ... write something to the array ... -}
  getElems a
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it's an `ST s [Int]` instead of `IO [Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use stToIO and getElems:

```
genArray :: IO [Int]
genArray = stToIO $ do
    a <- newArray (0,99) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
    writeArray a 0 1
    getElems a
```

Comment: Your answer solves this problem for good, which, however, I mistyped. Sorry for this.